# Polynomial regression in Python with different degrees

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I have `Y` which is a list of 100 elements, and I have two regressors: `X_1` and `X_2` (both are lists of 100 elements). I would like to use 3rd order polynomial for `X_1` and 1st order polynomial for `X_2` using `sklearn` module, i.e. regress `Y` against `X_1, X_1^2, X_1^3, X_2`. How can I do that?

Comment: Are your variables lists, np.arrays, or pandas dataframes? Do you have any restrictions on what libraries you can use?

Comment: They are lists but I can convert them to any other data type. I would prefer to use `sklearn` but if there is a better solution then I can use it too

Comment: Skkearn has excellent tutorials on regression. I'd recommend looking at them and trying to implement one of the examples yourself. You are looking for a polynomial fit. You can also use scipy which has many functions that will be useful to you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.